# CSS keyframe animation is pausing in middle then resuming again?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

This may be a dumb question (haven't done JS/HTML in a bit). I want this animation to be smooth all the way through but for some reason, it is stopping in the middle for a short period of time then resuming. Adding more steps to try and smooth the transition only seems to make is pause for longer. Is there a fix for this?

```css
#under {
      color: black;
      font-size: 28px;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-direction: alternate;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    
        }
    
        @keyframes example {
          0% {
              transform: translateX(-330px);
            }
            
          50% {
              transform: scaleX(3);
            }
        
          100% {
                transform: translateX(330px);
              }
        }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="under">
    <p> - </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: where is day() and updateClock()??

Comment: that's my bad let me edit those out. i don't think they're relevant to the question. They are just a clock and a date tracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep things moving evenly, you need to define your `scaleX` values at `0%` and `100%`. In addition, I changed your timing function from `ease-in-out` to `linear`. At `50%`, `translateX` is already at `0` since you defined the start and end values. For consistency, I added the `0` value at `50%`.

```css
#under {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1) translateX(-330px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(3) translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1) translateX(330px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="under"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the bouncing effect caused by the added scales! Was able to edit the values into something jazzy. IMO a better animation then what I had in mind ( the OP but smooth)